# Is "there could be" a idiomatic expression? If yes, when to use?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In my another question (["contents" or "content", which to use when talking about a book?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239153/109190)), I said

> **There could be** lots of topics on a book, such as the form/style, the author. In contrast to which, there could also be another topic, namely, the content.

where I use "there could be" to convey some kind of possibility of the topics on a book.

Although I found lots of people use this expression on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22There%20could%20be%22) and [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22There%20could%20be%22), I am not pretty sure that is an idiomatic expression.

So, is "there could be" a idiomatic expression? If yes, when to use?

Comment: Yes, it's fine to use _there could be_ to mean _it is possible that there are..._