# Are "on the other hand" and "nevertheless" interchangeable in some situations?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In my another post (["contents" or "content", which to use when talking about a book?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239153/109190)) I said

> ... she uses "contents" to refer to the things that are written in a book, I suppose "things" is interchangeable to "ideas".
>
> **Nevertheless**, Cambridge Dictionary clearly defines the word "content" as [ S or U ] with the meaning "the ideas that are contained in a piece of writing, a speech, or a film"

where I used "nevertheless" as a connection word. Usually, the "on the other hand" could also be used as connection. So, are "on the other hand" and "nevertheless" interchangeable here?

Comment: _Nevertheless_ means _in spite of what has just been said_. _On the other hand_ means _looking at the subject from the opposite point of view_. The two expressions are similar in use, but not identical.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. I agree with you on that. So, in the particular scenario in my OP, are they interchangeable?

Comment: I think _nevertheless_ is more appropriate.